# How to get a random value from the db that is different from the previous random value in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm making an app that users can generate random texts, texts are stored in the DB and the user can regenerate another text if they don't like the current one, but sometimes it returns the same random value, is there any way that i could show different random values each time?

```
$randomText = text::where('active','true')->get()->random();
```

this is the code that i use to get the random text, thank you, all answers are appreciated

Comment: need to more context. i.e. when this text is retrieved from the DB, does it get stored somewhere for the user specifically? or is it just showed on the screen? describe the end user experience please - how would they interact with your app?

Comment: @AlmazikG yes, they can store this random string/text but they could also get a new one if they don't like it, but i want it to always be different than the last time, they don't need to be unique, just they shouldn't be the same as the last one that user had generated

Answer (score 0):

If `random()` on laravel collection is not enough for you, you may try `inRandomOrder()` this is will be executed on `sql` side.

```php
$randomText = text::where('active','true')->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

And this will be translated to

```
"select * from `texts` where `active` = ? order by RAND()"
```

For MySQL here's what they say

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.

So it's not truly random either, but you also want it to be fast enough. It's also depending on the size of your data set.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it does the same thing, my problem is that sometimes user gets the same random text after refreshing and i want it to be different from the one that the user had generated